# Web crawling with R questions

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping

I'm currently using the XML package in R programming, and the POST and `xpathSApply` functions to do web crawling. When there are more than 2 values that satisfy the search criteria, I'd like to take just the first value.

In the image, I'd like to extract only the "짜증 나" part, located between `<li>` and `</li>`. Currently, I'm use the following command

```
tdReplace = xpathSApply(html, "//td[@class='tdReplace']/ul/li[2]/a", xmlValue)
```

without success. How should I go about fixing this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post samples in text, image texts are never encouraged, kindly edit your post.

Comment: Please include either the HTML as plain text or a link to the URL from which the HTML came.

Comment: link address is http://speller.cs.pusan.ac.kr

post_result = POST("http://speller.cs.pusan.ac.kr/PnuWebSpeller/lib/check.asp",
                       body = list(text1 = inputword), encode = "form")
    html = htmlParse(post_result, encoding = "UTF-8")

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [rvest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest) instead. It includes a function `html_node()`, which returns the first instance of the matching node.

Without seeing your HTML it is difficult to test but to parse HTML from URL `my_url`, something like this should work:

```
library(rvest)

my_url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node("td.tdReplace ul li a") %>%
  html_text()
```